# gpupgrade tool: can I upgrade from 6.x to 7.x?

Tags: upgrade, greenplum

Can I use **gpupgrade** to upgrade my Greenplum database from 6.x to 7.x?

documentation on greenplum.org only mentions 5.x to 6.x